# i got Python: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python

i have generated image in sequence and save in directory called `detected_car` folder, then i want to send them to JSON API like `https://api.generate_json/`, when I get json response from API it's also delete automatic with `os.remove("%s" %file)`, but it's always get that error. this is my code:

```
import cv2
import os
import json
import requests
import time

car_count = [0]
current_path = os.getcwd()
file = 'detected_car/car' + str(len(car_count)) + ".png"
path = '/home/username/Documents/path/to/image/dir%s' % file
result = []

def save_image(source_image):
    cv2.imwrite(current_path + file , source_image)
    car_count.insert(0, 1)
    with open(path, 'rb') as fp:
        response = request.post(
            'https://api.generate_json/',
            files=dict(upload=fp),
            headers={'Authorization': 'Token ' + 'KEY_API'})
        result.append(response.json())
        print(json.dumps(result, indent=2));

        with open('data.json', 'w') as outfile:
            json.dump(result, outfile)
    os.remove("%s" %file)
    time.sleep(1)
```

how to solve this. thankyou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file you write out appears to be saved into a different directory than the one you try to remove. This is due to `os.getcwd()` not returning a trailing `/`.

When you construct the path you send to `cv2.imwrite` you concatenate two paths with no `/` between them so you end up with:

```
"/a/path/from/getcwd" + "detected_car/car99.png"
```

Which results in a path that looks like this being sent to `cv2.imwrite`:

```
"/a/path/from/getcwddetected_car/car99.png"
```

But when you go to remove the file, you don't specify the absolute path, and ask `os.remove` to delete a file that doesn't exist.

I can think of 2 ways of solving this:

1. Add a trailing slash to `current_path`:

```py
current_path = os.getcwd() + "/"
```

2. Use an absolute path for both `cv2.imwrite` and `os.remove`:

```py
current_path = os.getcwd()
file = 'detected_car/car' + str(len(car_count)) + ".png"
temp_file = current_path + file

...

def save_image(source_image):
    cv2.imwrite(temp_file , source_image)

...

    os.remove("%s" %temp_file)
```